# How can the VC-dimension of Turing machine be finite?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, learning-theory, vc-dimension

The VC-dimension of a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ is defined to be the size of the maximal set $C$ such that $\mathcal{H}$  [cannot shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension). [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X96000509) shows that the VC-dimension of the set of all Turing Machines with $n$ states is $\Theta(n \log n)$.

However, suppose that we take the set of all such Turing machines, for $n$ sufficiently large so that the universal Turing machine is a member of $\mathcal{H}$. The result states that there exists a set $C$ (wlog, $C \subset \{0,1\}^*$) of size, say, $n^2$, such that $\mathcal{H}$ cannot shatter. To my understanding, it means that there exists a function $f : C \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ ("labeling"), such that for every $h \in \mathcal{H}$, it holds that $h \neq f$. Since the elements of $\mathcal{H}$ are Turing machines, I say that "$h$ computes $f$" when the machine $h$ implements $f$.

But $C$ is finite hence $f$ is clearly computable, thus there is some Turing machine $M_C$ which computes it, therefore $M_C$ can be simulated by the universal Turing machine, which is in $\mathcal{H}$, and this is a contradiction (since we assumed $\forall h \in \mathcal{H}, f \neq h$ ). Where is the problem with this argument?

Comment: Your definition of VC dimension is wrong. It’s the maximal size of a shattered set.

Comment: In your example, the property you state is very different from shattering. I suggest reading the definition of shattering on Wikipedia or on one of many online lecture notes.

Comment: Finally, the connection you attempt to make with universal Turing machines isn’t completely clear. This might have to do with your shaky definition of shattering.

Comment: A set C is shattered by H if for every labeling $f : C \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ there exists $h \in H$ such that $h = f$. If a set $C$ is not shattered by $H$, it means that there is some labeling $f$ such that there is no $h \in H$ where $h=f$. Why is that not the definition of shattering?

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that $f$ (the labeling for which there is no $f=h \in H$ ) is clearly computable, so every set $H$ which contains the universal Turing machine should be able to compute it, but there exists a finite universal Turing machine, which means there is such $f$, and there is a contradiction here

Comment: Example: think about $H =  sign(ax + b)$ for some reals $a,b$. Take $C = \{m =(0,0),n =  (1,0), r = (0,1), l = (1,1) \}$ and the labeling $f(m) = 0, f(l) = 0, f(n)=f(r) =1  $. Then you can't "compute $f$ with some $h \in H$" even though f is computable (which is totally ok since $H$ is a very limited model). My $H$ had the universal Turing machine in it, but still couldn't compute a computable function

Comment: To show that a class shatters a set of size $m$, you need to exhibit $2^m$ functions from the class.

Comment: Right, I don't see how is that relevant to my question. I am interested in the case where a class does not shatter a set.

Comment: Your condition on $f$ is too strict. You only care about its values on $C$.

Comment: Do you mean in the original example? I don't really care how $f$ behaves outside $C$. It can be just 0

Comment: I think that my example in the comment was a bit confusing. I order to show that $H$ shatters $C$, I indeed need to show that for every function $f : C \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, there exists some $h \in H$ which agrees with $f$. The number of such functions is $2^{|C|}$ which is what you wrote. But I care about when you know that $VC(\mathcal{H}) = n$, thus you know that there is a set of size $n+1$ which $H$ does NOT shatter, hence there is at least one $f$ that (informally) "you can't compute with $H$"

Comment: Your function is unfortunately not this function, since it’s just the constant 1.

Comment: Try proving that your counterexample works, using the definitions.

Comment: I defined $f$ to be that function (the labeling which makes it impossible to shatter $C$)

Comment: But your $f$ is easy. There is a different function that you can’t implement.

Comment: Oh, I see it now in the original example. My bad. Editing it now

Comment: @YuvalFilmus - I edited it

Comment: Try using the definitions more closely.

Comment: A universal Turing machine can simulate an arbitrary Turing machine *which forms part of its input*. You don’t account for that. The simulated machine should be part of $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me correct your definition of VC dimension: it is the largest size of a set which *can* be shattered.

If the VC dimension is $d$, then this means that for every set $C$ of size larger than $d$ there exists a function $f\colon C \to \{0,1\}$ which is not compatible with *any* function computed by an $n$-state Turing machine.

You are attempting to refute the claim that the VC dimension is $\Theta(n\log n)$ by showing that for any set $C$ of size $n^2$ there exists a single function $f\colon C \to \{0,1\}$ which is compatible with some function computed by an $n$-state Turing machine. However, what you need to do in order to refute the claim is to give a *single* set $C$ of size $n^2$ (say) such that *all* functions $f\colon C \to \{0,1\}$ are compatible with some function computed by an $n$-state Turing machine. Note the different quantifiers: you considered *all* $C$ and *one* $f$, but in fact you should consider a *single* $C$ but *all* $f$.

Finally, suppose that $M$ is a universal Turing machine having $n$ states. This doesn't mean that $M$ can compute arbitrary functions – in fact, $M$ computes a single function. What it does mean is that for any Turing machine $T$, $M(\langle T \rangle, x) = T(x)$. That is, if $M$ is given as input the pair $(\langle T \rangle, x)$ (where $\langle T \rangle$ is the encoding of $T$), then $M$ evaluates $T$ on $x$. This is different than what you claim, since the Turing machine being simulated is part of the input, that is, part of the set $C$.

In fact, in order to show that the collection of $n$-state Turing machines shatter a set $C$, you need to exhibit $2^{|C|}$ different Turing machines. Considering just a single universal Turing machine cannot possibly work.

Since there are only $O(n)^{O(n)}$ many different Turing machines having $n$ states (assuming the alphabet is fixed), this implies that the class of $n$-state Turing machines cannot shatter any set of size larger than $\log[O(n)^{O(n)}] = O(n\log n)$. This is how you get the upper bound on the VC dimension. The lower bound looks more challenging.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the first part: If I want to show that a class does not shatter a set, why can't I consider a single $f$? I need to consider a single $f$, then show that for every $h \in H$ (in my case, indeed $2^{|C|}$ Turing machines), it holds that $h \neq f$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right, to show that a class does not shatter a set you need a single $f$.